# Como mudar o status bar text color com CupertinoNavigationBar

Tags: ios, mobile, app, flutter

Estou tentando colocar o texto da status bar color do iPhone em cor branca
Eu ja tentei por no main o SystemUiOverlayStyle, com o statusBarColor e o brilho light mas não funcionou...

Eu tentei este código

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    statusBarColor: Colors.white,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Eu tentei criar o appbar para ios e android, mas eu quero colocar o status bar text color em Light, eu coloquei uma condiçao, que se for ios, ele cria CupertinoNavigationBar, e se for android, ele poe o AppBar normalmente, se eu coloco somente o Appbar sem ter o Navigation, e coloco o brightness light, ele funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Funciona perfeitamente:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Apply color in status bar
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red));
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa forma não funcionou! Mas eu achei uma outra forma de resolver este problema que pode ajudar outras pessoas que estiverem procurando também! 

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30114, funciona deste jeito porque CupertinoNavigationBar ele trabalha com o _wrapWithBackground() e quando ele está gerando, ele ja decidiu se vai ser brightness light ou dark, fazendo o SystemChrome nao alterar o status bar e para isso, esse link que coloquei acima, está pessoa recriou o CupertinoNavigationBar so que juntamente ao brightness de quando ela está sendo gerada!